# regex compare two numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, compare

can i somehow compare two numbers in regex?
i want regex that is correct for 10-12, but incorrect for 12-10. I mean that 10 must be smaller than 12.
I want to do it in Javascript.

Comment: I think you'll want to give a better description, or more examples, of what you require.

Comment: [Jeff's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html) answer to this !!

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values. Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (Javascript, whatever).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the input is always of the form X-Y, then why not use the split() function with '-' as the delimiter and then compare the two parts with >

You can't compare numerical values using RegExps.

Comment: +1 for your psychic powers in determining what the asker really wanted.

Comment: You might extract the numbers using a regex; you can't do the comparison.  Regexes are not the universal problem solving tool.

Comment: I think I knew what he meant, but it took me as long to formulate a response that you had already answered :)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use regex for this.  I'd split the string on the operator, then compare the two resulting numbers based on what operator I found (I'm assuming `10+12` and `12+10` would both be legal).

Comment: I mean that 10 must be smaller than 12

Comment: Regex is used for matching patterns, not comparing values.  I'd just split the string and use < or > to compare the two resulting numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're trying to roll two problems into one.

Regex is great at syntax (i.e. recognising numbers), but rubbish at semantics (i.e. recognising meaning). So regex will definitely help you recognise `x-y` but you're asking too much to then move on to reason about the relationship between `x` and `y`.

As often quoted;

> Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have
>   two problems. ([JWZ](http://www.jwz.org))

Or rather, you've now got three.