# PHP regular expression with self comparison

Tags: php, regex, comparison

I'm not sure if this is even possible but...

For the string

```
2-3
```

is it possible to construct a regex to check that the first part is less than second part?

Similarly, is it possible to construct a regex to check that the first part is greater than second part? Or if they are equal?

I know I could use explode and do it manually, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: No. Or at least difficult or unelegantly. [Perl 6 can](http://www.perl6.org/archive/rfc/197.html). But in PHP/PCRE you have to explain the regex how smaller numbers look. -- You have to compare the lengthiness of two numbers first `\d{2}-\d{3}`, then list piles of `[0-8]` alternatives to compare digits, as in http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html to accomplish that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex compare two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298753/regex-compare-two-numbers)

Comment: Yes it's possible for a defined range. Take a look at [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974342/date-range-validation-in-biztalk-edi-schema/17010983#17010983) to get an idea.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for some code without minimal understanding of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do it with just regular expression, you will need to use the regular expression to parse the string into separate parts and then use language logic to conduct the rest. for example.

```
$string = "2-3";
$regexp = "/([0-9]+)[+-\/\*]([0-9]+)/";
preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches);
```

Once you have parse the string

```
if ($matches[1] > $matches[2]) { }
```

Comment: That's what I thought. :( I will have to use something like this then.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of regex is just to match some patterns, it contains exactly matching operators, working with strings.

If you compare numbers, you use some math operators, therefore you should use a programming language to perform such operations. Why? Because math operations are supposed to work with such types of data as `int`, `float` and so on.

Regex will help you extract needed data from strings -> utilize the data using default tools.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always in that format, there's really no need for a RegEx

```
$string = "2-3"; 
$firstGreater = (int) $string[0] > (int) $string[2];
```